# Django - Save poll selected choices (not number of votes) in different classes of models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I'm facing difficulties in saving the selected choices of polls in different classes.

For example, I create questions and choices, and they are linked to each other (as from the tutorial of Django). In this tutorial, each time participants choose an answer, the selected choice is save as the number of vote (code given: `selected_choice.votes += 1`). I want to do more than that which is to save the whole answer, not just number.

This is code of saving number of votes:

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

I also create another class Fill which require participant filling some information before they do the polls. What I want is the selected choices are also saved in this class of models. The pictures will describe what I'm trying to explain. Red circle in the 1s picture is where the selected choices are aimed to save. Red circle in the 2nd picture are number of votes saved.

[image]

[image]

This is the code of Q1, Q2, Q3 created in CharField type to store selected choices.

```
class Fill(models.Model):
    Q1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    Q2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
    Q3 = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='')
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can help me out.
Thank you.

P/s: **My general idea is to save selected choices in the same list of personal data collected in order to know the selection of each person as describe in the 1st picture. So if you know any other ways rather then doing them in different classes then please enlighten me.**

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep track of each user (maybe using request.user) as a ForeignKey in your model and have whatever other fields you want in the model. This way, each response is tied to a user.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: Can you explain in more details please?
I wonder:
1. How to save the selected choices, not the number of votes +=1?
2. What do you mean by "have whatever other fields you want in the model"?

Comment: I think you have multiple models, but you can do all of this in one (or more). If you wanted to do it in one model, you can add a ForeignKey field to your model using the link I updated. However, you need to make it a hidden field (so you don't show it in the form but update it before saving the model). Like this: https://gist.github.com/exp0nge/99fbc7e534b965313a7b **Edit**: If you want to give optional choices, you need to put 'blank=True' into the model parameters. Secondly, if you use the method I'm talking about, then you will know what option was ticked.

Comment: I'm getting problem in saving the selected choices. How can I save the selected choices instead of saving number of votes as the code above (selected_choice.votes += 1)?

Comment: Why don't you use a ChoiceField instead?

Comment: Thank you. I tried to use ChoiceField. It seems to work for me. But what I can't do at the moment is I can't display what I want. For example, I have 3 questions and each has 2 choices. I want to display these questions and choices and between each question there're different images. Like this, [image1] - question 1 with choices - [image2] - question 2 with choices.... I tried to use both {{ survey.get_location_display }} and {{ survey.education}} but it doesn't work. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: You should have  different tuples with the choices for each question. Post your model.py code for where you are doing this.